# Adding TestNG to the project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I have added TestNG as a library and according to my homework, I should have libs with .jar file inside (as you can see in the picture). I have 2 questions:

1. How it can become green (I clicked on libs and "add to library", it didn't help)
2. Can I avoid using libs folder with this .jar inside, will it reduce productivity of my project?

[image]

Comment: 1) I believe that it's red because it's not added to GIT. 2) That jar contains classes created by TESTNG, if you will not have that jar -> you wont be able to use testng classes.

Comment: but i have added this .jar in external libraries, isn't it enough? and how can i add it to git? can it be done inside Idea?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/set-up-a-git-repository.html#add-new-files

Comment: Use a build automation tool like *maven or gradle*. These tools with automatically manage the jar dependencies required in your project.